# Uncaught (in promise) : message : "expecting a right parentheses "

Tags: apex

With this code, when I execute the query in the inspector I get the result, however when I call my class in my component I do not retrieve Data and I get this error in the console:

```
      message : "expecting a right parentheses"
```

and tells me that the error that exists in the last line of code:

```
     cumul = database.query(Query);
```

some help please .

```
 @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List <AggregateResult> getMonthly(){
    User u = [SELECT id, Volume__c FROM  User WHERE id=: UserInfo.getUserId()];
    List<AggregateResult> cumul = new list<AggregateResult>();
    List<Account> acc = [SELECT Id,RecordType.DeveloperName FROM Account WHERE ownerid =: UserInfo.getUserId()];
    List<String> accString = new List<String>();
        for( Account c: acc)
            {
            accString.add(c.Id);
            }
    String year = String.valueOf(System.Today().year());
    String  productFamily = 'light';
    String Filters ='';
    Filters = Filters + 'Year__c = \'' + year +'\' ';
    Filters = Filters + 'AND Sales__r.Account__r.Station_Account__c IN '+ accString +' ';    
    Filters = Filters + 'AND Product_Family__c = \''+ productFamily +'\' ';
    String Query = 'SELECT Sales__r.Account__r.Name ,CALENDAR_MONTH(Date_technicalfield__c) Month, ';    
        if (u.Volume__c == 'Liter') {
            Query = Query + 'SUM(Quantity_in_L__c) Quantity ';
        } else {
            Query = Query + 'COUNT(id) Quantity ';
        }
        Query = Query + 'FROM SalesK__c WHERE ' + Filters + 'GROUP BY Sales__r.Account__r.Name ,Date_technicalfield__c ORDER BY Date_technicalfield__c ASC';
    cumul = database.query(Query);
    return cumul;
    }
```

Comment: Could you please share the js of your component?

Comment: Well, if this is an error in the Apex portion, then the first step would be to `system.debug(Query);` to see if there is anything wrong with the way you're building your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's likely your `IN` syntax that is causing problems.

If you want to build your own, you need to have make something like:

```
IN('value','value','value')
```

and you need to build this syntax up yourself (including escaping quote marks)

However, if you use binding, the system will use local context variables and do it for you.

Change your `IN` syntax to:

```
Filters = Filters + 'AND Sales__r.Account__r.Station_Account__c IN :accString ';
```

Further example (this is the whole method):

```
User u = [SELECT Id, Volume__c FROM  User WHERE id=: UserInfo.getUserId()];
Account[] accounts = [SELECT Id,RecordType.DeveloperName FROM Account WHERE ownerid =: UserInfo.getUserId()];

String year = String.valueOf(System.Today().year());
String  productFamily = 'light';
String filters = '' 
 + ' Year__c = :year '
 + ' AND Sales__r.Account__r.Station_Account__c IN :accounts '  
 + ' AND Product_Family__c = :productFamily ';  
 
String query = ' SELECT Sales__r.Account__r.Name, CALENDAR_MONTH(Date_technicalfield__c) Month, '
 + u.Volume__c == 'Liter' ? ' SUM(Quantity_in_L__c) Quantity ' : ' COUNT(id) Quantity ' 
 + ' FROM SalesK__c WHERE ' + filters + ' GROUP BY Sales__r.Account__r.Name, Date_technicalfield__c ORDER BY Date_technicalfield__c ASC';
              
return (List<AggregateResult>)Database.query(query);
```

As you can see, this is about **HALF** the amount of code in your example.

There are some useful lessons here that you managed to avoid by not attempting this solution -

1. Binding directly from a SOQL query as with `accounts`.
2. Binding to and `IN` clause.
3. Directly returning the results of your `AggregateResult` without assigning to a variable.
4. A better method of string concatenation.
5. A more compact `if:else` syntax for the volume param.

Comment: yes , there is a problem in my IN syntax but I don't know how to fixe it , I tried your proposition but I get another error message:  `"Only variable references are allowed in dynamic SOQL/SOSL." `

Comment: I modified it to `    Filters = Filters + 'AND Sales__r.Account__r.Station_Account__c IN :'+ accString +' ';    `

Comment: This is my all query that I use in the inspector and give me the result `SELECT Sales__r.Account__r.Name ,CALENDAR_MONTH(Date_technicalfield__c) Month, SUM(Quantity_in_Kg__c) Quantity FROM SalesK__c WHERE  Fiscal_Year__c ='2022'  AND Sales__r.Account__r.Station_Account__c='0012000002aU8xXAAD'  AND Product_Family__c ='light ' GROUP BY Sales__r.Account__r.Name ,Date_technicalfield__c ORDER BY Date_technicalfield__c ASC `

Comment: When I used the binding inside the string The error changed and passed to the next line , I get now as an error message  `
"unexpected token: Product_Family__c" `

Comment: do you mean that I should make it like this `  Filters = Filters + 'AND Sales__r.Account__r.Station_Account__c IN : accString'  +'\'  ;    
    Filters = Filters + 'AND Product_Family__c = \''+ productFamily +'\' '; `

Comment: I would appreciate if if you tried my solution, given you got a lot of free help here.

Comment: Your solution was the first lead I followed, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is what solved my problem
I added this to my code

```
String accString ='';

   for( Account c: acc){
    accString = accString +'\''+ c.Id + '\',';
   }
    accString = accString.substring(0, accString.length()-1);

    Filters = Filters + 'AND Sales__r.Account__r.Station_Account__c IN ('+ accString +  ') AND Product_Family__c = \''+ productFamily +'\' ';
```